# Converting an SSL Cert to byte array then back to a certificate again

Tags: c#

I've got a lot of self-signed certificates that will be assigned to connections.  Rather than storing them on a file share, I want to store these in SQL Server. I can of course load a certificate from a file into X509Certificate2 but saving that to the database is causing issues.

This is the test code I'm working with:

```
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("idp.pfx");

        var convertedCert = new X509Certificate2( bytes,"password");
        string test = convertedCert.ToString();

        byte[] test2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(test);
        var newCert = new X509Certificate2(test2);
```

What I'm trying to do is read in a `.PFX` file and save it to a SQL Server database. I need to be able to write the `.pfx` file to the database and call it up later for encrypting / decryption for that specific connection.

But right now I'm only trying to switch formats back and forth to prove this is going to work before adding in the storage to the DB.

When I run the above code I get the error on the last line of code:

```
  An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Cannot find the requested object.

So the X509Certificate2(byte[]) is treating this as the string version of the method X509Certificate2(string fileName) and trying to load the file.

I think what is happening is that the byte array conversion is not converting it to the right format...  But what is the right format?

Comment: Why not write it as a byte array to the database?  It isn't text, let alone UTF-8.  No conversion is necessary.

Comment: You are getting yourself a **text** representation of the cert via `convertedCert.ToString();`. Why do you treat that text representation as if it were the byte data of the certificate? Perhaps try using `X509Certificate2.Export` and `X509Certificate2.Import` methods (or the appropriate X509Certificate2 contstructor instead of `Import`)...

Comment: Thanks Amy.  Sometimes I'm so busy looking in the forest for trees and not seeing the single tree in the forest.